# Why does Indy 10's echo server have high CPU usage when the client disconnects?

Tags: delphi, indy

When I disconnect echo client like :

```
EchoClient1.Disconnect;
```

client disconnects fine... 
but EchoServer does NOT EVEN register client disconnection 
and it ends up with high process usage  !?!?

in every example and every doc it says that calling EchoClient.Disconnect is sufficient !

anyone, any idea ?

(I am working in Win7, could that be a problem ?)

Server code :

```
procedure TForm2.EServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  SrvMsg.Lines.Add('ECHO Client connected !');
end;

procedure TForm2.EServerDisconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
 SrvMsg.Lines.Add('ECHO Client disconnected !');
end;
```

problem is "TForm2.EServerDisconnect" never executes !?!?

Comment: Need to show some server side code

Comment: just seting Active to true and simple OnConnect and onDisconnect procedures...

Answer (score 3):

Find out for yourself by using the debugger.

If your program has high CPU usage, assume it's stuck in a loop. The debugger can help you figure out which loop, and why. While the server is running in the debugger and exhibiting the problem, press the "pause" button. The debugger will interrupt your program and show you the line your program was executing. Use the *call stack* to show you how your program got to that line. Find the loop that you suspect is the culprit. Resume and pause your program a few more times to see whether you always stop somewhere in that same loop. Now analyze the code to figure out why the loop doesn't terminate.

You might have to activate a different thread; the main GUI thread will probably be waiting in a call to `GetMessage`, which is normal.

Make sure you're using [the latest version of Indy](http://indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx). Don't use the version that came with your copy of Delphi.

Comment: Never use develompent snapshots of Indy, its "release" versions are unstable enough.

Comment: @User, the only release version available from Indy's Web site is six years old. The version that came with Delphi 2010 [didn't even compile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358111/). Download from SVN.

Comment: I did all of that already... I know what the problem is, I just don't know how to resolve it! Server does NOT disconnect the client even when the same is disconnected! The client's thread on server never shut's down! It must be a bug of some kind or...!

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: heh, even nightly snapshots are outdated, and it is not first time we had broken "release" version. I'd recommend switching to ICS while few library dependencies made, then.

Comment: Yeah... I agree! It seems Indy is dead!

Comment: If you don't like the nightly snapshots from the Web site, then make your own by simply running `svn update`. @Virtuo, when you did the debugging, what did you learn? Is your program stuck in a loop? What is that loop trying to do? How did your program get there? What is the client's thread doing, if it's not shut down? How *should* it get to the point where it calls `OnDisconnect`?

Comment: oh no, i don't want to go into that... and waste hours if not days! Anyway, THX!

Comment: @Virtuo, after I suggested you use the debugger to find where your program is stuck, you said, "I did all of that already." I guess you really didn't, unless you just mean you don't want to spend hours explaining what you learned. But unless it takes *hours* just to reproduce the problem, it will not take you hours to do what I've suggested. Simply press the "pause" button in the debugger and look around to see where you are.

Comment: There is no exception of any kind so it is difficult to determine the problem! And I did "try" the "pause" button. The echo thread on client app closes on disconnect but NOT the coresponding thread on the server, and it just goes wild! Why... well it's a mystery to me! Indy doc's say it is a simple echo server that should work in a way I tried, but it simple does not! My delphi threading/indy experience is not actule the very best so after already wasted X hours...  naturally I ASKED a "question" with hope that someone already knows the answer... THX for your input!

Answer (score 2):

The code shown is NOT THREAD SAFE.  Any Indy event that provides access to a TIdContext object is fired in the context of a worker thread that runs that object.  Access to UI components must be done in the context of the main thread instead.  If you do not follow that rule, all kinds of unexpected bad things can happen.  You need to synchronize with the main thread, eg:

```
uses
  ..., IdSync;

procedure TForm2.EServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(ClientConnected);
end;

procedure TForm2.ClientConnected;
begin
  SrvMsg.Lines.Add('ECHO Client connected !');
end;

procedure TForm2.EServerDisconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(ClientDisconnected);
end;

procedure TForm2.ClientDisconnected;
begin
  SrvMsg.Lines.Add('ECHO Client disconnected !');
end;
```